# How to solve $20(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor+\left\lfloor x+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$ analytically?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How to solve this analytically?

$$20(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor+\left\lfloor x+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

where $\lfloor .\rfloor$ is the floor function.

I attempted to solve this equation numerically for the first 7 numbers, after which no solution exists. However, solving numerically is a pain.

How can I solve this analytically?

My working (an example for the first 3-4 reals )

$$19x-21\lfloor x\rfloor =\left\lfloor x+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

- When $x$ is between $0$ and $0.5$, there is a single solution at $x=0$.
- When $x$ is between $0.5$ and $1$, we have $19x=1$, which means no solution in the given interval
- Next, solving on $[1,1.5]$, we have $19x-21=1$, which gives us another solution in the given interval.

And so on, until no solutions occur for two or 3 tries, at which point all solutions have been obtained.

I haven't yet found all the elements as it would obviously take forever. (I know there are 7 solutions as I graphed these on Desmos to confirm my idea.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I estimated the first few values using a calculator, it seems to be recursive, which is good for me. But this is still not very rigorous. Is there any other way to do this that's more rigourous?

Comment: I think at `$x=04` you meant `$x=0$`?

Comment: Use the elementary bounds $x-1\le \lfloor x \rfloor < x$ to bound the expression $\mathrm{LHS}-\mathrm{RHS}$ between two lines, such that the zeros are restricted to the interval $[-0.167,7.167]$. This tells you that $n=\lfloor x \rfloor$ may only take the values $-1,0,\ldots,7$. Then, observe that $\lfloor x+\frac12\rfloor=n,n+1$. This gives you finitely many linear equations in $x$ to trial. Back substitute the solutions into the original equation to filter the correct ones and you're done.

Answer (score 4):

Write $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + (x - \lfloor x \rfloor)$ and then split it into the cases where $0 \leq x - \lfloor x \rfloor < 1/2$ and $1/2 \leq x - \lfloor x \rfloor < 1$. Now the term $\lfloor x + 1/2 \rfloor$ evaluates to $\lfloor x \rfloor$ in the first case and $\lfloor x \rfloor + 1$ in the second.

In both cases, $x$ can be expressed in a linear equation in terms of $\lfloor x \rfloor$; the scaling factor in front of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ ensures there are only a finite number of solutions. Since $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer you can just test all candidates.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

Denote $\{x\}$ the fractional part of $x$, then
$$\Longleftrightarrow 19\{x\} = 3[x] +\left[\{x\} +\frac{1}{2} \right] $$
We deduce that
$$-1<3[x]<19  \Longleftrightarrow 0\le [x] \le6$$

**Case 1:** If $\{x\} < \frac{1}{2}$, then
$$19\{x\} = 3[x]  \Longleftrightarrow  [x] < \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{19}{2} \Longleftrightarrow [x] \le 3$$
then for $[x] =n \in \{0,1,2,3 \}$, we have
$$ \{x\} = \frac{3n}{19}\Longleftrightarrow x = n +\frac{3n}{19}  \qquad \text{for } n= 0,1,2,3 \tag{1}$$

**Case 2:** If $\{x\} \ge \frac{1}{2}$, then
$$19\{x\} = 3[x] +1 \Longleftrightarrow  [x] \ge \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{19}{2}-1\right) \Longleftrightarrow [x] \ge 3$$
then for $[x] =n \in \{3,4,5,6 \}$, we have
$$ \{x\} = \frac{3n+1}{19}\Longleftrightarrow x = n +\frac{3n+1}{19}  \qquad \text{for } n= 3,4,5 \tag{2}$$
**Attention**: We need to remove the case $n = 6$ as in this case, $\{x\} = \frac{3*6+1}{19} = 1$ that cannot occur ($\{x\}$ must be in $[0,1)$).

From $(1),(2)$, we have 7 solutions
$$x \in \left\{0, \frac{22}{19}, \frac{44}{19}, \frac{66}{19}, \frac{67}{19}, \frac{89}{19}, \frac{111}{19}  \right\}$$

Comment: $7$ is not a solution.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I should remove the case $n = 6$, see the line I added in the solution.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!